# What is/was the default JS/HTML formatter in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm, eslint

Or even better, what is the closest ESLint/Prettier ruleset?

I'm trying to enforce ESLint on a legacy AngularJS project, and the maintainer is reluctant to accept this enforcement. In order to placate him, I want the ESLint ruleset/config to match his current style as closely as possible.

I questioned him, and he told me that he is using formatting on save. I expect he is using whatever is default, because I could not get him to tell me what configuration he is using. It makes me think he has not changed the default.

Comment: **1)** Current IDE version can run Prettier on Save: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/prettier.html#ws_prettier_run_automatically_in_current_project **2)** He can run ANY external tool using File Watcher: it will/can be triggered for each modified file once file is saved or modification is detected (see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/using-file-watchers.html#troubleshoointgFileWatchers) **3)** IDE's own formatter uses own rules and CANNOT run on Save. But with additional plugins (like Save Actions for example) this can also be achieved (not tested myself though).

Comment: @LazyOne your comment is better then the currently accepted answer. Thanks! That said, I don't think the maintainer in question is using a WebStorm recent enough to be using prettier by default.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The IDE own formatter doesn't work on save, so he must be using some linter/beautifier.

The default WebStorm code style preferences are not based on any existing standards/ruleset

Comment: semi answered i guess